line gradient based on dynamic inputs
I am wondering if it is possible to create a custom gradient coloring for a line chart based on a field or parameter value. Based on my research, it does not seem to be possible, as I couldn’t find any documentation supporting this functionality.
Although this post includes exactly the output I am looking for, it achieves the result using manually inputted values, which does not suit my needs --> LINK
My goal is to achieve something similar dynamically. For example, if the completion field is at 25%, the gradient would start at the x-position of 0, and for the first 25% of the line length, the color would match the value from the color field. The remaining portion of the line would use the same color but with an opacity of 0.3.
I suspect this might not be possible in Vega-Lite, but I would be happy to hear if someone has a workaround or a solution for this.
Thank you!
Sample:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"startDate": "2024-01-15", "category": "a", "value": 1, "color": "red", "completion": 0.25},
      {"startDate": "2024-01-17", "category": "a", "value": 1.5, "color": "red", "completion": 0.25},
      {"startDate": "2024-01-18", "category": "a", "value": 1.5, "color": "red", "completion": 0.25},
      {"startDate": "2024-01-19", "category": "a", "value": 1.5, "color": "red", "completion": 0.25},
      {"startDate": "2024-01-22", "category": "a", "value": 2, "color": "red", "completion": 0.25},
      {"startDate": "2024-02-15", "category": "b", "value": 2, "color": "blue", "completion": 0.45},
      {"startDate": "2024-02-17", "category": "b", "value": 2.5, "color": "blue", "completion": 0.45},
      {"startDate": "2024-02-18", "category": "b", "value": 2.5, "color": "blue", "completion": 0.45},
      {"startDate": "2024-02-19", "category": "b", "value": 2.5, "color": "blue", "completion": 0.45},
      {"startDate": "2024-02-22", "category": "b", "value": 3, "color": "blue", "completion": 0.45}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "startDate",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Date"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Value"
    },
    "detail": {
      "field": "category"
    }
  }
}


Instead of a line that has a gradient, consider adding a second layer where you visualize the completed vs target for each day. Or of course a gantt chart would be a good option here also.
Here is a basic example:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-15",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-17",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-18",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-19",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-22",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 2,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-15",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-17",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2.5,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-18",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2.5,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-19",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2.5,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-22",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 3,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.value * (datum.completion > 0 ? datum.completion : 0)",
      "as": "completed"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "area", "interpolate": "monotone"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "startDate", "type": "temporal", "title": "Date"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Value"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"stroke": "white", "type": "area", "interpolate": "monotone"},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"value": "#85C5A6"},
        "x": {"field": "startDate", "type": "temporal", "title": "Date"},
        "y": {"field": "completed", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Value"}
      }
    }
  ]
}

This could be a starting point for you:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-15",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-17",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-18",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-19",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-01-22",
        "category": "a",
        "value": 2,
        "color": "red",
        "completion": 0.25
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-15",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-17",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2.5,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-18",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2.5,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-19",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 2.5,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.45
      },
      {
        "startDate": "2024-02-22",
        "category": "b",
        "value": 3,
        "color": "blue",
        "completion": 0.8
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.value-0.2", "as": "lineWidth"}],
  "spacing": 0,
  "facet": {"field": "startDate", "type": "ordinal"},
  "spec": {
    "width": 70,
    "mark": {
      "type": "bar",
      "color": {
        "expr": "{'x1': 0,'y1': 1,'x2': 1,'y2': 1,gradient: 'linear', stops: [{offset: 0, color: datum.color},  {offset: datum.completion, color: 'white'}]}"
      }
    },
    "encoding": {
      "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Value"},
      "y2": {"field": "lineWidth"}
    }
  }
}


thank you very much, you solved my problem, it is exactly what I was looking for :)
